# Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to execute code with  WebDriver but getting this exception, I do have WebDriver reference, Any thoughts what might be causing this exception

> "Error: TAEF: [HRESULT: 0x80131604] A failure occurred while preparing to run tests in class ''. (Failed to create an instance of ''. (Failed to instantiate a managed test class. 
>   (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)"

Comment: Are you using package manager or you have added references yourself?

Comment: Looks like whichever dll references `WebDriver.dll` is a strong-named dll. But `WebDriver.dll` is not strong named. The rule is, if your dll is strong-named, all references it has also must be strong-named. I believe you can sign it yourself http://codehotfix.com/how-to-sign-third-party-assemblies/